# FLASK_ENV seems to be ignored (can't enter debug environment)

Tags: python, flask

According to the Flask documentation,

> The flask script is nice to start a local development server, but you
>   would have to restart it manually after each change to your code. That
>   is not very nice and Flask can do better. If you enable debug support
>   the server will reload itself on code changes, and it will also
>   provide you with a helpful debugger if things go wrong.
>
> To enable all development features (including debug mode) you can
>   export the FLASK_ENV environment variable and set it to development
>   before running the server:

```
$ export FLASK_ENV=development 
$ flask run
```

However, in my very simple example, code changes still don't take effect until I restart the server. I've set up the particular script I want to run with `export FLASK_APP=hello.py` and the script is as follows:

```
from flask import Flask, url_for, request, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!!"
```

While the Flask development server is running, I change the return value by adding or removing an exclamation mark and saving the file. Then I refresh the page on `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` in Chrome, but the number of exclamation points is unchanged. Once I quit Flask in the terminal using `Ctrl-C` and restart it and then refresh the page again, I get the proper number of exclamation points.

This is on a Mac, Python 3.6.0 (Anaconda), Flask 0.12.

Am I misunderstanding how the development server can help me, or is there anything else you think I should check? I'm quite new to Flask.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try

```
FLASK_APP=app.py FLASK_DEBUG=1 TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD=1 flask run
```

`FLASK_DEBUG` will get you the behavior you're looking for now; `TEMPLATE_AUTO_RELOAD` will get you the behavior you'll need as soon as you starting using templates.

Comment: That works - but it looks like it only works if it's all on the same line. That is strange to me, because I would have expected that once an environment variable is set (even on a previous line in the terminal) it would be available to future programs run in the same terminal session, at least. Do you know what I might be missing here?

Comment: Depending on your shell, you might need `export FLASK_DEBUG=1` to persist the setting in your environment. Without that, it only applies on the line.

Comment: Strange, I could have sworn I was doing that. But I can't reproduce it, now when I use `export` it works properly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

```
$env:FLASK_ENV = "development"
flask run
```

That's worked for me on my Win10 laptop running VS code

Answer (score 2):

Looking at `app.config` contents I discovered variable `ENV='production'`.

Set `ENV='development'` in config file and it worked. `FLASK_ENV` variable does not even exist.